# How to limit Skype CPU usage

Tags: linux-mint, cpu-usage, skype

I use Skype for messaging only.

But it is consuming some real CPU time when idle.

I would like to limit the Skype process' CPU usage.

Can it be done?

I am using Linux Mint 17.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update (2018)

This library worked for an old Skype (<= 4.3). It will not work with modern Skype for Linux. But it does not have to anyway, I do not see excessive CPU usage anymore.

### Original answer

[Skype poll fix](https://github.com/ValdikSS/skype-poll-fix) addresses this specific issue.

It prevents Skype from frantically polling so often.